# Test whether or not log-in system is protected against sql injection

Tags: mysql, pdo, sql-injection, defensive-programming

So for a school project I have to make a site with a log-in system. It has a username and password field, and a submit button. It compares the username and password with those in a MySQL database. If the combination is in the database, the user may proceed, else they are redirected to the log-in page. I use prepared PDO statements for my database connection.

Now my teacher wants me to test the safety by performing sql attacks on the log-in system. Unfortunately I have no idea what to put in these boxes, and what would be the outcome. For example, I have tried putting values in both username and password fields that will return true, like this:

```
1==1,  1===1,  0 is null
```

But I do not know whether or not I have succeeded and if attackers may access or truncate my database by these sort of statements.

Html code:

```
<form method="post" action="includes/login.php">
<input type="text" name="gebruikersnaam" >
<input type="password" name="wachtwoord" >
<input type="submit"  value="login">
</form>
```

Php authentication:

```
$myusername=$_POST['gebruikersnaam']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['wachtwoord']; 
$sql="SELECT * FROM leerling WHERE leerlingnummer='$myusername' and wachtwoord='$mypassword'";
$sql2="SELECT * FROM lop WHERE gebruikersnaam='$myusername' and wachtwoord='$mypassword'";
$statement2=$conn->prepare($sql2);
$statement2->execute();
$count2=$statement2->rowcount();

if($count2==1){proceed}

$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$count= $statement->rowcount();

if($count==1){proceed}

else {deny access}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection -- P.S The code could help us.

Comment: As I said, I have tried these things, however I do not know if any system was jeopardised.

Comment: And without code how can we help you?

Comment: You use mysqli but don't use prepared Statements.. your current code is not safe! Please read http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @MarcoAcierno I use PDO, not mysqli. $conn is my PDO connection.

Comment: Ok, the problem is the same. -- http://it2.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Answer (score 1):

Imagine this query:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE email=? AND password=? LIMIT 1
```

Now imagine the values would be `foo@bar.hello` and an empty string for `password`:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='foo@bar.hello' AND password='' LIMIT 1
```

This would not be harmful if these credentials are not in your database. Now lets give different input:

For `email` we fill in an empty string, and for `password` we insert `' OR 1=1` (Note the first apostrophe)

Your teacher wants you to find out whether this means your SQL server will execute the following query:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='' AND password='' OR 1=1 LIMIT 1
```

SQL is a declarative language with which you declare the expectations you have for your result. If your server would interpret our input as stated above, the first users `id` would be considered correct, simply because one is equal to one.

Comment: Well, I have tried this, and it returns 'wrong credentials' so this means it denies me access. Now the funny part is, I do not, at least not exactly, know why. Does the prepare() function protect me here?

Comment: Because the creators of the `prepare` function made sure that when you place a question mark, nothing but 1 input for the value before the equal sign gets evaluated. `password=?` will make sure only the value for password is considered a correct input. Your teacher wanted to show you that this is a valid defence against SQL injections. She should also tell you not to give variables Dutch names.

Answer (score 1):

As it is, it is susceptible to SQL injection

The thing to look at when trying to inject is can I close the statement I'm in right now and add more to the end.

so if you enter username = `123456' --` the SQL statement becomes `SELECT * FROM leerling WHERE leerlingnummer='123456' --' and wachtwoord='unimortant'`

the -- starts a comment so all it does is select whatever student number is entered ignoring the password.

PDO has good alternatives to prevent this from happening called  [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements). You declare your SQL queries and only enter where user infromation is going to be entered by using a `?` or `:lable` and then bind user input to those points. The page does a way better job at explaining it. This way all user data is clearly seperated from the rest of the command and will be treated as a litteral string rather than a command. Stopping SQL injection.

Comment: My question is actually, does this script protect me from doing that? Does the prepare() function prevent this from happening?

Comment: Update clearifies. It does not, you have to use prepared statements. (prepared statements don't help if you dont use the parameter binding part of it).

Comment: This won’t work, you can’t prepare multiple statements.

Comment: You're right, Didn't think of that, What I edited it into should still work though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$_REQUEST['username']}' AND password = '{$_REQUEST['password']}";
```

Write query in such format will avoid sql injection.

```
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?';
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(1, $_REQUEST['username']);
    $query->bindParam(2, $_REQUEST['password']);
```

Or pass the parameter to mysql_real_escape_string function and then pass to queries.

```
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['username']);
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['password']);
```